# Git rebase fix conflict, where does that fix get applied?

Tags: git, version-control, conflict, rebase

Lets say I am working on a branch off master and someone does large amounts of work on master that I now need to apply to my branch.

If I use rebase master and have conflicts - where are those fixes applied.
Are they applied with my branch changes so ontop of master or are they changing the work done within master changing its history -
*Master's history, not my new branches history, my branches doesn't matter as it's only master that is live none of the changes made into the new branch are*.
Am I applying them ontop of where master's head is so not harmful to the public master branch.

Also if I have to later do this again with more conflicts where are those applied ontop of the last conflict resolutions, within those resolutions or somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase` only can have conflicts while changing the working directory - that's it, while preparing the next commit. So, any fix you do, it will show up in the commit you are applying.

Remember `rebase` does `cherry-pick`, which records a *new* commit. So *that* new commit (that's different from the original one you are `cherry-pick`ing) will have any necessary changes.